# HTML5 Chrome App Cache: manage and storage limit

Tags: google-chrome

We require a very large number of images to be saved to the chrome application cache, so far the most we have tested is 4.1GB (120 x 9MB and 120 x 27MB) and 3.8GB (14000 x 250KB). This seems to work great. 
We'd love to know what the actual limits are (if any), so that we can plan accordingly before hitting them.

Our two outstanding questions are:

What are the storage limits (if any), when using chrome application cache?

Is there any way to clean up the items in the app-cache?
Can you cherry-pick items to remove that are no longer in use, or do you need to completely clear it out every so often and re-download?

Comment: 4.1 GB? wow that's quite a lot! - Does the user have the ability to pick/choose which ones they want/need? I'm trying to imagine an app of any kind that I'd consider downloading that takes more than 1 GB even... let alone a "web app" - Can I ask what this app does?

Comment: @scunliffe It's actually acting as a kiosk for a business client and not intended for casual users.